# SSIS - SharePoint to SQL without Adapter Addin?

Tags: sql, sharepoint, ssis, wss

Im looking to Extract a SharePoint List (WSS 2.0) to a SQL(2005) Table using SQL Server Integrated Services.

First off I am aware of the "adapter" that does this from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd365137.aspx however I'm just wondering for compatibility purposes if it can't just be done "out of the box".

There are only a limited number of "Data Flow Sources" to select as alternatives and I am unsure if any of these would be able to work in a similar way either directly to SharePoint or via SharePoints web services (e.g. http://server_name/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx) From the list of these sources it looks like the best option would be the OLE DB connector, but not sure how it would do this.

Any help you have would be great,

Mark

Answer (score 2):

You can use Script Source task to talk to WSS Lists Data Retrieval Web Service. But I would strongly recommend using the custom Add-in.

[Overview of WSS Webservices](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/klaus_salchner@hotmail.com/SharePointWS11152005045049AM/SharePointWS.aspx)

[Calling Sharepoint Webservices From SSIS](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/drjohn/archive/2007/11/03/ssis-calling-sharepoint-web-services-from-the-data-flow.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunatly its in a tightly monitored corporate environment, and so 3rd party or non-"out-of-the-box" arn't really considered, although this method looks more promissing and friendlier to the corporate environment.